# Is there an alternative to anonymous sign in from firebase for flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I think Firebase is great, but I really don't like the anonymous sign in system. I've got the following system to implement: On his First App Start, the user should be signed up automatically and anonymously. His user credentials should be saved on his device. Whenever the user opens the app again, these credentials should be used for the users sign in.
When the user deletes the app, his user credentials should be deleted from his devices and from everywhere else.
The app I'm working on is built with flutter.
Are there any alternatives to the anonymous sign in of firebase?
I need an anonymous sign in method that still works fine with a huge amount of users.
Thank you!

Comment: sounds like Firebase anonymous sign in is exactly what you want. what are you trying to achieve that Firebase doesn't have?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a sqlite login system local to the device. Or are users going to login with same credentials on multiple devices?

Comment: @MehranBehbahani Yeah, almost, there is one issue: If a user deletes the app the anonymous credentials stored in firebase are still there. If that happens often, you've got a huge amount of useless stored user accounts in firebase. And I think every time a user opens the app again, a new account is created. And I don't know how to implement the following in flutter: onappinstall: create anonymous user, oneveryappopening: sign in with those user credentials, oneappdeletion: delete anonymous user from firebase.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah, users should be able to log into an ios/android app version and a web app version with the same credentials

Comment: As far as I know there is no solution to remove those unused sign in records for uninstalled users. If you wanna access the user list later and somehow make use of it, I can suggest you write some code that fetches the whole user log in list along with its meta-data and filters them based on the date of last log in. this way you have a list of active users (with some error. if a user has just uninstalled, they will still be in the list)